# Is there a way to make Chrome ask me about every request?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Yes, I really want the browser ask me before it loads anything (a [redirect](https://superuser.com/q/618043/64359), an image, CSS, whatever). This makes the browser rather unusable, but I need this for debugging my application.

If it's not possible, then I may get happy with a different browser, too.

Comment: Do you want to use that feature with extensions or just by taking settings? Firefox has a setting option to ask to redirect everytime.

Comment: @Biswa IIUYC setting would be easier. I'll look at Firefox. I guess, I'll need all the help a browser can offer.

Comment: Haven't used it personally but [uMatrix](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix) which is a fork of [HTTP Switchboard](https://github.com/gorhill/httpswitchboard) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the loading of any resource type in the chrome dev tools. i personally prefer the firefox dev tools for this sort of thing because you can opt to have it disable for all pages and not just the one you're on. I'm pretty sure chrome has this feature as well. There's also a thousand extensions that let you drill down on these sort of things. Firebug for one also has a load of functionality where resource blocking / analytics is concerned.